# Very slow Slew Rate after an 8V regulator

Tags: simulation, electronics

I have a requirement to provide a regulated 8V supply to power a FET. The regulated 8V is supplied from a DC bench power supply and needs to have a very slow slew rate to replicate someone turning the current up (from 0mA to when 8V is reached) which is the current manual method, and capable of drawing 500mA for later use (though the current specs indicate 50mA on this 8V rail).

I realise after my research the slew rate of 1 second or so done by the manual testing, is likely not feasible to recreate.

I currently have an LM293ES regulator to do the actual regulation and my current research is leading me down the path of op amps for the slew rate side of things.

Do I carry on with this path the op amps?
If so, can I simulate this via Qucs or is there a better free tool? I do have access to Altium too...
What kind of slew rate would be suitable for this application?

I am very new to designing any circuit like this so explanation of decisions would go a long way to my understanding and for the future.

Comment: Welcome to E.SE, Matthew. I'll flag this question for migration to https://electronics.stackexchange.com where all the EE guys hang out. (Don't double-post it.) You need to clarify your thinking on the requirements. You say that the current will be turned up when 8 V is reached but it can't work like that. You've got three variables, V, I and R. You are controlling V and R is, I presume, determined by the load that means that ***I*** will be determined by ***V/R***. For a given load you can control ***V*** or ***I*** but not both.

Comment: 1. "*What kind of slew rate would be suitable ...?*" I think you've already said that you require 8 V/s slew rate. 2. Be aware that your new driver circuit will need some "headroom" for it to be able to output 8 V. I'd say you'll need a 12 V supply.

Comment: @Transistor Thanks. I didn't realise there was another forum. And yes my wording was correct - I questioned the wording supplied to me and a demos ensued. - The voltage was set to 8v, and then the current to 0A. The voltage then immediately dropped to 0V. When the supply was switched on the Voltage only increased when the current was increased. The load resistance is set so I presume that in this case, 8V is the target and we're controlling the current up to that point and no more.

Comment: I did also find this: [link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/397616/how-do-i-decrease-the-slew-rate-of-an-op-amp) - would this actually works? 1V/S would be fine...

Comment: Can you describe the application a bit more? What is the device under test or what does this operation do? That information will help determine linearity, repeatability and accuracy requirements.